# Создание новой формы div при нажатии на кнопку и как осуществить перенос информации из 2 input. Как осуществить?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function out() {
  let value = document.getElementById('email').value
  if (!value) return;
  let container = document.createElement('div');
  container.className = "container";
  container.innerHTML = value;
  document.getElementById('out').appendChild(container)
}
```

```html
<div id="out"></div><input type="input" id="email" name="email" class="klics">
<input type="input" id="state" name="state" class="iskl">
<button onclick="out()" class="btn">Применить</button>
```

Comment: Где форма, 2 input ? Может чуток html добавите, откуда куда поточнее опишете..

Comment: Не совсем правильно задал вопрос изначально. Имеется два input, но информация из них выводится в блок только из одного input, нужно код в js переделать так, чтобы информация выводилась из  2-х input.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно осуществить:

```js
function out() {
  //получаем значение поля email
  let value = document.getElementById('email').value

  //получаем значение поля state
  let value2 = document.getElementById('state').value

  if (!value && !value2) return;
  let container = document.createElement('div');
  container.className = "container";

  //выводим значения обоих полей
  container.innerHTML = value + ' ' + value2;
  document.getElementById('out').appendChild(container)
}
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
<input type="input" id="email" name="email" class="klics">
<input type="input" id="state" name="state" class="iskl">
<button onclick="out()" class="btn">Применить</button>
```